# Betta fish has white growth on his back. What is it and how can I treat it?

Tags: aquarium, fish, psychology, diseases, betta

My Betta fish has had a white growth on his back for over a week. Pictures linked below. I'm keeping him in a 5 gallon tank and am replacing <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> of the water bi-weekly. No filter because the one included with the tank ran too hard and disturbed the water and the fish.

I'm worried in general for his health since even before developing this growth he's never been quick to eat (I give him TetraO pellets and bloodworms). The fish was kept in extremely poor conditions for most of his life and even though they're better now, I worry it may be a little too late.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE :) Please use the "edit" button to reshape your question and add a question ;) How it is shaped now, there are a lots of answers possible, which is not the way this site works. I assume you want to know, what the white spot is? If you additional want to know, how you can help your betta to stay healthy, please feel free to ask a new question for this :)

Comment: Maybe the answers to this questions will help you: [white spot](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23580/white-patches-spots-on-my-betta) , [betta slow eating](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10897/is-the-betta-fish-dying-of-old-age)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White spot is a murderous disease that is highly infectious disease caused by a parasite that may be causing this. It has killed 3 of my neon tetras before and 1 of my honey-comb catfishes. Maybe that was because it hit him bad and he was obese xD.

Now on the serious part, it is lethal so getting medicine fast is vital to he your little fish safe. Hope you get the medicine!